# Use JSON in Unity

Tags: c#, json

Im currently trying to use the use the following JSON repsonse (from https://mempool.space/api/address/1wiz18xYmhRX6xStj2b9t1rwWX4GKUgpv) in Unity.
(Bitcoin Adress is only the example from the API provider)

```
{
 address: "1wiz18xYmhRX6xStj2b9t1rwWX4GKUgpv",
 chain_stats: {
   funded_txo_count: 5,
   funded_txo_sum: 15007599040,
   spent_txo_count: 5,
   spent_txo_sum: 15007599040,
   tx_count: 7
 },
 mempool_stats: {
   funded_txo_count: 0,
   funded_txo_sum: 0,
   spent_txo_count: 0,
   spent_txo_sum: 0,
   tx_count: 0
 }
}
```

For that, I created the following class

```
      [Serializable]
      public class chain_stats
      {
          public int funded_txo_count;
          public int funded_txo_sum;
          public int spent_txo_count;
          public int spent_txo_sum;
          public int tx_count;
      }
[Serializable]
public class Wallet
{
    public chain_stats[] chain_Stats;
}
```

The Debug.Log(www.text) return the correct JSON string.
This is how I tried to put the data in there:

```
  Debug.Log("Processing Data, please wait");
        WWW www = new WWW("https://mempool.space/api/address/1wiz18xYmhRX6xStj2b9t1rwWX4GKUgpv");
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log(www.text);
        if (www.error == null)
        {
           
            chain_stats Wallet  = JsonUtility.FromJson<chain_stats>(www.text);


            Debug.Log(Wallet.funded_txo_count);
        }
```

However, Debug.Log(Wallet.funded_txo_count) is only returning 0. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your C# class structure does not match the JSON response structure. Think about it: your Wallet class contains a field that is an array of chain_stats. Do you see any arrays in the JSON response? No. So your structure needs to change. For simple JSON like this, [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com) works wonders. And in C#, we don't generally make fields public. Instead, if something needs to be exposed outside the class, we use a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) (particularly auto-implemented properties).

Comment: Got it! I used json2csharp to make a new class and using JsonConvert instead of JsonUtility to put it in there worked! Thanks so much :)